# oracle sql group by column which count them

Tags: sql, linux, oracle

I ran below query to fetch count of data which I can see in output but it does not working as I wish

How can I print count of col6 & col7 in output?

Am I clear?

```
select col1, col2, 
col3, col4, decode(col5,'S','Success','F','Failed'), col6, col7, count(*)
from mytable 
where col1 in (select FIELD1 from temp)
and col8 = 4
group by col1, col2, col3,col4,col5,col6,col7
```

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.  Counting columns in the `group by` clause is not very interesting.  The value is always `1` (well, unless the value is `NULL`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works

```sql
select count(col6), count(col7)
from mytable 
where col1 in (select FIELD1 from temp)
and col8 = 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the proper `aggregate function` and remove the `col6` and `col7` from `GROUP BY` clause following query:

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4, decode(col5,'S','Success','F','Failed'), 
      count(col6), count(col7), count(*) -- used count for col6 and col7
from mytable 
where col1 in (select FIELD1 from temp)
and col8 = 4
group by col1, col2, col3,col4,col5 -- removed col6 and col7 from here
```